# How to get the return value from a external rest service using SSJS

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

How to call external rest service using SSJS not using java code. I would like to call an external URL and then it returns a value, how to capture this value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please enlighten us. And why no Java code?

Comment: My recommendation would be to 
a) use this as an opportunity to embrace Java.
b) run it client-side from a JavaScript AJAX request in the browser instead
c) if on 10.0.1, use a LotusScript agent and return the content to a temporary document, which your code uses
Most people with experience of this will have gone down either the Java or JavaScript approach, and it provides experience for future development. The LotusScript approach is not ideal, but will give reusable experience for Notes Client development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something a little like this:

```
var url:java.net.URL = new java.net.URL("https://www.google.com");
var conn:javax.net.ssl.HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");

if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var strReturn;
    var strOutput;
    var br:java.io.BufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while((strOutput = br.readLine()) != null) {
        strReturn += strOutput;
    }
    conn.disconnect();
    return strReturn;

} else {
    conn.disconnect();
    return "URL failure: " + conn.getResponseCode();
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your response. I am looking similar kind, but i want to read the returned json value. How can i do it.

Comment: @user12039174: What have you tried so far? Please enlighten us.

Comment: As Sven has said, it's easier for us to assist if you can post some code that you've tried. The best approach is definately doing this in Java, if you really want to work in SSJS then you'll need to add a SSJS library probably something like this: https://xomino.com/2013/12/18/safe-json-parsing-in-xpages-ssjs/ to convert the json string to an object you can work with.

Comment: Andrew, it is obvious that @user12039174 did no research or coded something. The user just wanted YOU to do his job. For free.

Comment: Hi Sven, i was sick and so late response. If i know something about this ssjs i would have pasted my code but i am totally new to this one and so requested some examples. I always have a respect to the wise people who can address my questions and also double respect who criticize others. I am just changing the technology and so got into this issue. I am always thankful to Andrew that his code gave me a boost to get into ssjs as i was a python developer.Thanks

Comment: @user12039174: You were unable to do some reasearch before posting the question here? You can easily find a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191273/consume-rest-service-in-xpage

Comment: I read the above solution but i dont want to go with complete java solution, the maintenance people requested us not to use java code